# MongoDB:Too many connections from Secondary

Tags: mongodb

We have a 3 node replica set running on MongoDB 3.2, and having an issue with Replication.

On Primary server, connection count will keep increasing as one of the secondary will keep making new connections to primary until the connection count is too high(30000+) and primary is down.

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

329

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

576

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

576

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

576

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

588

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

590

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

596

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

602

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

770

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

1492

[root@EKAUSHALPRD mongo]# netstat | grep 27017 | wc -l

1895

There is not a single query or write operation running on the server.All we have is these kind of requests keep coming from one of the secondary while the other one works fine:

```
   query: { ismaster: true }  ntoreturn: -1 ntoskip: 0
```

10.117.241.104:27017  <<--  10.117.241.104:41470   480 bytes  id:83e9c1 8645057 - 7129
        reply n:1 cursorId: 0

In mongo logs we see first a new connection is established and then 
Successfully authenticated as principal **username** on **dbanme**

Comment: Replication members do not connect to each other as `username`; it looks like this activity is related to a script or application running on the originating IP.